# Can't create archives with php zip library

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop for homework a MVC PHP app that archives some files, app which I'm building on a Zend Server in Windows 7 (if it matters).

Here's the setup : I have this form in a view :

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>What would you like to store?</h3>
    <form action="<?php echo URL; ?>archives/archiveAction" method="POST"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <label>Select the files you'd like to store</label>
        <input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" >
        <label>Select your favorite compression algorithm</label>
        <select name="type_of_archive">
            <option value="zip">ZIP</option>
            <option value="tar">TAR</option>
            <option value="gzip">GZIP</option>
            <option value="bzip2">BZIP2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="add_files" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And then I'm passing it to the responsible controller action:

```
public function archiveAction()
    {
        if(isset($_POST["user_id"]) && isset($_POST["type_of_archive"]) && isset($_FILES['upload']))
        {
            $time = new DateTime();
            if ($_POST['type_of_archive'] == 'zip')
            {
                Helper::zipFiles($_FILES['upload'],"./".$_SESSION['username']."/",$_SESSION['username']." - ".$time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }
        }
    }
```

The zipFiles function itself is below :

```
static public function zipFiles($files, $dir, $name)
{
    $location = $dir.$filename.".zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($location, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }
    $num_of_files = count($files['name']);
    for($i = 0;$i<$num_of_files;$i++ )
    {
        $zip->addFile($files['tmp_name'][$i]);
    }
    $zip->close();
    return $location;

}
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any errors. What I'm trying to do is create a zip file in a directory. All I'm getting is that my browser is downloading an empty file called archiveAction. Anything I'm missing here? If I keep retrying the script just hangs after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you use `$files['tmp_name'][$i]`. If you `print_r` your `$_FILES` you will see that `$files['tmp_name'][0]` (for example) is just a file name without a path. So when you execute `archiveAction` script tries to find file `$files['tmp_name'][$i]` in a directory where it is (script) is run. Sure there's no such file, as it is stored in  your `/tmp` or some other directory for temporary files.

So, you should either first copy your uploaded files (`move_uploaded_file` function) to some specific location, path to which you know, and create zip archive using these copied files and full path to them. For example, copy them to `uploads` folder of you site. And use:

```
$zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/' . $somefile_name);
```

Or you can find out path to your temporary files folder (check `php.ini`) and use:

```
$zip->addFile($temporary_path . $files['tmp_name'][$i]);
```

Comment: Funny enough, a var_dump on $_FILES reveals this :  ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpD54C.tmp" [1]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpD54D.tmp" }

Comment: Either way, your solution helped me a lot in dealing with the fact that it doesn't work with relative paths. Thanks again!